# how to use bash script to loop through two files

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have two folders each containing 500 files, 
folder 1:

```
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default_numberalignment_per_read
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default_numberalignment_per_read
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R3.fastq.gz_matches_default_numberalignment_per_read
```

and another folder (folder 2) with these

```
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R1.fastq.gz_matches_default_filtered
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R2.fastq.gz_matches_default_filtered
HI.2622.001.Index_19.ED18_ND1W27-2_288_R3.fastq.gz_matches_default_filtered
```

The first file in folder one corresponds to the first file in folder 2 and so on. I want to keep those lines from file 2 that the first column matches the first column of file one. If it was a single file, I would easily use

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' file1 file2 > file_match
```

But I have 500 files, so I need to run it through looping. I do not know how to loop through 2 files! any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: You talk about columns, but you never say what column delimiter your using (and using the ordinary whitespace as delimiter, you only have one column in each file). Also, it would be good to know what the expected result should be.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think what the user has posted are file *names* and they want to apply their awk command to pairs of such files, with one file taken from each directory...?

Comment: @steeldriver Huh, that's what I get for using my phone to read... Well that just means there's even more info missing.

Comment: Maybe you have a look at the join command, in case awk is broken. :)

Comment: Is the order of the various contents of *column 1*s relevant?  Are the respective *column 1*s sorted?

Comment: Experimenting with the `awk` code shows that the order of the 1st column's contents doesn't seem to matter:  `cmp <(awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' <(seq 50 | paste - - - - | unsort) <(seq 50 | paste - - - | unsort)) <(awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' <(seq 50 | paste - - - -) <(seq 50 | paste - - - ))`, outputs no difference.  Note that either way the `awk` output is sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the files for each folder in arrays:

```
f1=( /path/to/folder1/* )
f2=( /path/to/folder2/* )
```

Then iterate over the numeric indices of the arrays

```
for idx in "${!f1[@]}"; do
    awk ... "${f1[$idx]}" "${f2[$idx]}" > "${f1[$idx]}.matched"
done
```

Comment: Since the names are nearly identical, maybe a check whether they match is appropriate.

Comment: @glenn jackman, thanks for the tip, I eventually used for idx in "${!f1[@]}"; do
    awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' "${f1[$idx]}" "${f2[$idx]}" > "${f1[$idx]}.matched_try1"
done. and it gave my my desired output